# Send Monit E-Mails via Exim

Tags: email-server, monitoring, exim, monit

I installed monit on an Ubuntu 18.04 server and I would like to configure it to send e-mails to my personal e-mail address. I heard that I can send them via the installed exim. However, it does not work. As I am new to both mail servers and monit, I am not sure how to fix it.

In `/etc/monit/monitrc`, I added

```
set mailserver 127.0.0.1 port 25
```

and

```
set alert user@example.com
```

where instead of `user@example.com` I use my personal e-mail address.

To test whether it works, I also pasted

```
check file alerttest with path /.nonexistent
   alert user@example.com
```

into the file, again with my personal e-mail address instead of `user@example.com`.

Despite having checked documentations etc., I am not sure what I am missing here.

The e-mails should be sent directly from the server and not via e.g. Gmail.

Comment: In general: start by ensuring that your mail server works as intended before you start troubleshooting in Monit. So check the exim logs, confirm that you can connect on port 25 , check is you can send an email message for example from the command-line with the `mail` or `mailx` command etc.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was indeed that Exim was not sending e-mails.